# File finder Java program : Homework

Tags: java, command-line

This is my homework, but please read my problem description first.

I have to write a Java program as

***a.***       Path of the directory will be passed to the program as command line argument. Then program will prompt for a file name and find all the files with that name.
If no argument is passed, program should search directory from previous run. Do not use any database.

***b.***      If user types exit/quit/bye, program will stop execution.

***Problem description:***

*My problem is that question says that I have to take directory name from command line and if it is not passed I have to take previous entered directory. But when we pass command line argument we need to run the program. It means each time I have to run the program to pass command line args. **So how can I remember  the previous one if argument not passed (as in question I can't use database)**. *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what do you mean with "program should search directory from previous run". So i will try to answer 2 possibilities :

1. previous run from the same session. ( that just being run )

   > In the order to do this you should create a singleton that store all
   >   of run in ArrayList, and get the latest path. Memento pattern might also be another solution for this.
2. previous run from same/different session ( means maybe run yesterday, or last month, or last year ) and the computer might have been turned off between each run.

   > For this, I think you should write the path to a default file using FileWriter or BufferedWriter. And then create
   >   a FileReader or BufferedReader to read from this file to get the last
   >   path being run.

Comment: If I use first 1 logic, my confusion is that if I used singleton pattern and stored prev entry, but when I again run the program I will loose that value, isn't it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. If this is the concern you should use the second option.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the name of the actual directory name in a file (which will be the "previous" directory name when you re-run with no parameter)

*Persistance* is the key. You'll have to *persist* (store) the *state* outside the application, somewhere where it can *survive*.